# Multithreaded WPF application isn't supporting more than 2 or 3 parallel threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library, mvvm-light

i have a WPF application which downloads file using a Multi-Threaded approach and it consumes nearly 100% of my bandwidth(and this is what I require) but when i move the code from this WPF application to my main WPF application which has many other utilities inside it then my bandwidth consumption reduces to nearly 25% or less. After examining my project i realized that the application starts all the thread and then some of the threads goes to sleep or wait and only 2,3 thread works on the downloading and then when they finish their work the other 2,3 threads woke up. I don't understand why this is happening as it was working fine in my other WPF Application. I am using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger for message passing so that i could invoke the downloader or uploader to start their work. I have tried threadpool, System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke but all of them gives the same result they work good in standalone WPF application but not in the main Application.

Update:

what i come to know is that when i start my application and let it run for some time without doing anything for a min or two. then the application starts performing better and gives the same result as standalone application did.

Comment: You can only support truly parallel operations if the number of threads is less-than-or-equal to the number of cores on you PC. If you have 4 cores and 16 threaded operations running then you will see gaps (lower cpu usage of individial threads) as the operating system context switches cores between threads. Context switching itself is has an overhead so _lots_ of threads can be worse for system performance. If 12 of the threads end, the remaining 4 operations will continue with far higher cpu usage.

Comment: My PC Specs are:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4900MQ CPU @ 2.80GHz with 32GB RAM and 512GB SSD

Comment: And  why the application starts giving same performance after some time. is there any way to Stop or abort all the threads currently used by the application before i start my download or upload threads

Comment: Your system, specs don't matter. The lesson here is that computing power is finite and if you make it busy with lots of operations, individual operations will be slower, regardless of how many threads you use.

Comment: Performance is probably coming back because the startup process for your `main application` is expensive and runs on more than one thread. Don't micro-optimise here. Is the system fast enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel extensions and Task Parallel have big history and already enough polished. 
I would suggest to investigate application load level for threads, it sounds high enough.

As Gusdor wrote you cannot pull lots of threads to limited number of cores in the processor.
At a time only one thread is executed per core. Then thread is stopped, context unloaded to the memory and instructions from the next thread is loaded.

No magic, check the program and heavy loading from another processes.

Comment: ok i am  looking into it